# JavaScript causes CSS transition to not work

Tags: javascript, html, css, transition

I'm trying to load style from css file and menu from js file.

In the js file I use "document.write" and this causes the css's transition to not work.

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="menu.js"></script>
        <div class="trans">aaa</div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS (file name: style.css)

```
.trans {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 250px;
    transition: 1s;
    -moz-transition: 1s;
    -ms-transition: 1s;
    -o-transition: 1s;
    -webkit-transition: 1s;
}
```

JavaScript (file name: menu.js)

```
str = `
<div>menu</div>
`;
document.write(str);
```

**update - solution:**

Thanks to all respondents!
Thanks to you I got to the solution :-)

adding **async** so the script would not block the animation:

```
<script async type="text/javascript" src="menu.js"></script>
```

replaceing

```
document.write(str);
```

with

```
document.currentScript.insertAdjacentHTML("beforebegin", str);
```

so the document would not be rewritten.

Comment: Ensure that your script loads after the CSS is loaded.

Comment: Don't use [document.write](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/write) as it will clear your entire document

Answer (score 0):

Try this for your JavaScript (assuming you want this div at the end of the body):

```
var myDiv = document.createElement("div");
myDiv.className = "abc";
var textNode = document.createTextNode("menu");
myDiv.appendChild(textNode);
document.body.appendChild(myDiv);
```

Comment: `var textNode = document.createTextNode("menu"); myDiv.appendChild(textNode);` is absolutely fine. But note that `myDiv.textContent = 'menu';` does ***exactly*** the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your code is fine, but is missing something. Your transition is not working because you did not specify a transition.

You should make a trans:hover, trans:clicked or any other state you want, with a css attribute in it, like background-color: red; Then when you hover, click or whatever, you'll see your transition working just fine. However, your document.write is bad practice. It can fuck things up.

Try this:

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="menu.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="trans">aaa</div>
        <div id="abc"></div>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS

```
.trans {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 250px;
    transition: 1s;
    -moz-transition: 5s;
    -ms-transition: 5s;
    -o-transition: 5s;
    -webkit-transition: 5s;
}    

.trans:hover {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Scripts

```
document.getElementById("abc").innerHTML = "menu";
```

Try it out: https://jsfiddle.net/jlanssie/Ljhawtqx/5/

Answer (score 0):

`document.write(str)` will overwrite tour document so `<div class="abc">menu</div>` will *replace* `<div class="trans"></div>` and that causes your *entire* CSS not to work, *not just transitions*. Use `innerHTML` instead.

```js
let container = document.querySelector('.trans');
let str = `
<div class="abc">menu</div>
`;
container.innerHTML = str;
```

```css
.trans {
    text-align: center;
    padding-top: 250px;
    transition: all 1s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -ms-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 1s ease;
}


.trans:hover {
  background-color: #c00;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="trans"></div>
```

For transitions the syntax is:

```
transition: [transition-property] [transition-duration] [transition-timing-function] [transition-delay];
```

Also remember not all css properties support transitions.